# Delete Keyword Count VB.net

Tags: vb.net, keyword-search

I Have Problem About this count Keyword after that appear that stuff

Here Code

```
Public Sub searchayumiKn()
    Dim myKeyWords() As String = TChat.Text.Split(" "c)
    Dim mySQLQuery As String = "SELECT AIRes FROM T_GKnowledge WHERE "
    Dim KeyWordCount As Integer

    For KeyWordCount = 0 To myKeyWords.Length - 1
        Dim strKeyParameter As String = String.Format("@Param{0}", KeyWordCount)
        Dim strWhereClause As String

        If KeyWordCount = 0 Then
            strWhereClause = String.Format("Keyword LIKE {0}", strKeyParameter)
        Else
            strWhereClause = String.Format(" OR Keyword LIKE {0}", strKeyParameter)
        End If
        mySQLQuery &= strWhereClause
        cmdhikari.Parameters.AddWithValue(strKeyParameter, String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "%", myKeyWords(KeyWordCount)))
    Next

    With cmdhikari
        .CommandText = mySQLQuery
        .Connection = conayumi
    End With

    Try
        dthikari = New DataTable
        dahikari.Fill(dthikari)
        answers.DataBindings.Add("text", dthikari, "AIRes", True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Caution")
    End Try
    KeyWordCount = 0
    TChat.Clear()
    Return
End Sub
```

Got Error @param bla". can anyone delete this count?
i just need original of data record. Not Count every time. just not using count. so freely record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move out from for this declaration

```
Dim strKeyParameter As String = String.Format("@Param{0}", KeyWordCount)
Dim strWhereClause As String
```

it's make duplicate declaration the same parameter

hopefully could be useful

regards
Ade Nurhuda

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for revision, my bad for that's